# How to ignore custom elements in VuePress to avoid the "Unknown custom element" error?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I am creating documentation for a W3C web components library (Vanilla JavaScript) using VuePress. However, **my "custom" web components are generating an error due to VuePress trying to "recognize" them as Vue components** the very first time the page loads.

**Once the page is loaded my web components work as expected**, but the error is there anyway.

This is the error I am getting:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <nova-timeline> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <TimeLineWrapper> at docs/.vuepress/components/TimeLineWrapper.vue
```

I have created the following structure related to Vuepress

```bash
.
├── docs
│   ├── .vuepress
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── TimeLineWrapper.vue
│   │   ├── config.js
│   │   └── theme
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── Timeline.md
```

And this is part of my code:

```html
// docs/.vuepress/components/TimeLineWrapper.vue
<template>
    <nova-timeline ref="timeline"></nova-timeline>
</template>
<script>
  import timeLineJson from "./data/TimeLineData";

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        timeLineJson: timeLineJson
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$refs.timeline.data = this.timeLineJson.data;
      this.$refs.timeline.configuration = this.timeLineJson.configuration;
    }
  };
</script>
```

```html
// This is my W3C web component:
<nova-timeline ref="timeline"></nova-timeline>
```

What I like to know is how to "ignore custom components", I mean where or how to do this kind of configuration using the VuePress way.

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  // Use a `RegExp` to ignore all elements that start with "nova-"
  // 2.5+ only
  /^nova-/
]
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, I'm trying to do the same. Can you please show me how and where you import the custom element (nova-timeline)?

Answer (score 2):

I finally manage to find how to add my ignored elements,

1) Create a file named `enhanceApp.js` in `docs/.vuepress/theme`

2) Place this content inside of it:

```js
// https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/custom-themes.html#app-level-enhancements
export default ({ Vue, options, router, siteData }) => {
  Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
    // Use a `RegExp` to ignore all elements that start with "nova-"
    // 2.5+ only
    /^nova-/
  ];
}
```

Now, the error will disappear since Vue will ignore our custom web components.